# How to get filename with timestamp in ssis

Tags: ssis

I have an input file which has to loaded daily to my table. I receive files in the following format sample sample_20120518_160754.CSV. Time stamps may vary, it is not current time stamp

I have used expression to get the filename along with date, but how can i get timestamp of the file.

This was the expression i have used to get the filealong with date.

```
"sample_" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("yyyy", (DT_DATE)@[User::p_varAsOfDate]), 4) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("dd", (DT_DATE)@[User::p_varAsOfDate]), 2) + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("mm", (DT_DATE)@[User::p_varAsOfDate]) +"_"  +".CSV"
```

this expression yeilds result

sample_2012145_.CSV  now i want time stamp of the file also.

Answer (score 8):

Here's the expression that will give you the datepart + the time part as well. You can put additional delimiters in between to accomplish the format that you want.

```
(DT_STR, 4, 1252)DATEPART("yyyy", @[System::ContainerStartTime]) + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("mm", @[System::ContainerStartTime]), 2) + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("dd", @[System::ContainerStartTime]), 2) +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("hh", @[System::ContainerStartTime]), 2) +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("mi", @[System::ContainerStartTime]), 2) +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("ss", @[System::ContainerStartTime]), 2) +
```

you can edit the above expression and use another variable of your choice. I chose the ContainerStartTime because of the ease.

Comment: Hi Rajiv, i tried to use this expression, but this expression yeilds Current time stamp. i may recive file at morning 6 and i load the file at afternoon 2. so in this case it doesn't works.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to extract the data from the CSV files? And why exactly are you constructing the expression to extract the date and time? The sample_2012145_.CSV doesnt look right either "2012145" does not make any sense.

Comment: i receive files everyday, and my file name would be sample_yyyyddmm_hhmmss.csv format. So i pass Asofdate as input varibale.This is the expression which i use to get my filename "sample_" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("yyyy", (DT_DATE)@[User::p_varAsOfDate]), 4) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("mm", (DT_DATE)@[User::p_varAsOfDate]), 2) + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("dd", (DT_DATE)@[User::p_varAsOfDate]) + ".CSV"

Comment: I still dont understand why you are creating this expression. Do you use this expression to dynamically set the file name in your Source component? If so, there are better ways to handle this.

Comment: You can simply use GETDATE() instead of system variable

Answer (score 3):

`@[User::miFilePath]+"AnyName"+"_"+(DT_WSTR, 04) YEAR( GETDATE() )+(MONTH(GETDATE())>=10 ? (DT_WSTR, 02)MONTH(GETDATE()): "0"+(DT_WSTR, 02)MONTH(GETDATE()))+  (DAY(GETDATE())>=10?  (DT_WSTR, 02)DAY(GETDATE()): "0"+(DT_WSTR, 02)DAY(GETDATE()))+"_"+RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("hh", GETDATE()), 2) +RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("mi",  GETDATE()), 2) +RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252)DATEPART("ss",  GETDATE()), 2) + ".txt"`