# Sql Server SSIS package Flat File Destination file name pattern (date, time or similar)?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm scheduling a SSIS package for exporting data to flat file.

But i want to generate file names with some date information, such as foo_20140606.csv

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Related: [How to get filename with timestamp in ssis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685999/how-to-get-filename-with-timestamp-in-ssis)

Comment: Can you please tell how to make this parameterize when we deploy the package in remote server, I need to make the path configurable in the external server via config table.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With the help of expressions you can make connection dynamic.

Select your flat file connection from Connection Managers pane. In Properties pane, click on Expression(...). Then choose ConnectionString Property from drop down list and in Expression(...) put your expression and evaluate it.

Expression build -

```
For day : (DT_STR,4,1252)DAY( DATEADD( "dd", -1, getdate() ))
For month: (DT_STR,4,1252)MONTH( DATEADD( "dd", -1, getdate() ))
For Year:  (DT_STR,4,1252)YEAR( DATEADD( "dd", -1, getdate() ))
```

Example expression(you need to tweak as per your requirement) -

```
"E:\\Backup\\EmployeeCount_"+(DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "yyyy" , getdate() ) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "mm" , getdate() ), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "dd" , getdate() ), 2) +".txt"
```

which is giving `E:\Backup\EmployeeCount_20140627.txt` as value.

Please note - You need a working flat file connection so first create flat file connection whose connectionString property is then going to be replaced automatically by expression.

You can follow these step by step articles as well.

[ssis dynamically naming destination](http://jahaines.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/ssis-dynamically-naming-destination.html)

[SSIS Dynamic Flat File Connection](http://sqlknowledgebank.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/ssis-dynamic-flat-file-connection.html)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ooh, I like yours better, it has purdy pictures! :)

Comment: Can you please tell how to make this parameterize when we deploy the package in remote server, I need to make the path configurable in the external server via  config table.

Comment: If you are using `SSIS catalog`  as deployment model, then you have the option to configure Project/Package level parameters and connections. On SSMS, go to the  Integration Services Catalog then just right click on Project/Package, you will see the option.

Answer (score 2):

Select your file connection in the Connection Managers, go to the Properties and click on the (...) beside expressions.

In the editor select ConnectionString from the Property column.
In the Expression text box, you can enter something like "rootNameOfFile" + (DT_WSTR, 50)(DT_DBDATE)GETDATE() + ".csv"

Evaluate your expression to make sure you're getting what you expect, and voila!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have SSDT and thus can't edit this with a GUI here is how you edit the SSIS package directly:

Before:

```
<DTS:ConnectionManager
      DTS:refId="Package.ConnectionManagers[DestinationConnectionFlatFile]"
      DTS:ObjectName="DestinationConnectionFlatFile"
      DTS:DTSID="{C69365C4-EF12-4606-980B-E8862EE997A4}"
      DTS:CreationName="FLATFILE">
      <DTS:ObjectData>
```

After:

```
<DTS:ConnectionManager
      DTS:refId="Package.ConnectionManagers[DestinationConnectionFlatFile]"
      DTS:CreationName="FLATFILE"
      DTS:DTSID="{C69365C4-EF12-4606-980B-E8862EE997A4}"
      DTS:ObjectName="DestinationConnectionFlatFile">
      <DTS:PropertyExpression
        DTS:Name="ConnectionString">"C:\\Exportdir\\Filename_"
 + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART("yyyy",GetDate()) +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mm",GetDate()) ,2) +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("dd",GetDate()),2) + "_" +
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("hh",GetDate()),2)+
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART("mi",GetDate()),2) + ".csv"      
      </DTS:PropertyExpression>
        <DTS:ObjectData>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily give the dynamic file name for flat or csv  file in SSIS package like DataFeed_{yyyyMMdd} .txt eg. DataFeed_20181212.txt. simply go to flat file connection manager property and define the expression value and in another way you can define the package level variable and this variable you can use in expression and as per environment you can able to define folder location by using configuration file .dtsconfig file

more details @ [ssis dynamic file name for flat file](https://rajeevdotnet.blogspot.com/2018/12/ssis-dynamic-file-name-for-flat-file.html)