# SSIS - Filename with Query output

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Currently  I am working on SSIS package. I am very new to SSIS. I am trying to name the file with date from the query. I created execute SQL task and assigned it to variable and tried to use the variable in File System task.

But I am keeping getting errors. I am using ADo.net connection to connect to oracle database. My task will be something like this.

```
Position_DATE where DATE = select TO_CHAR(PAM_CHECKPREVBUSINESSDAY(sysdate),'yyyymmdd') AS DATE from dual
```

Please help with the query... I have been struggling with this task for 2 days.....

Comment: go throw http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Including%20the%20Date%20in%20a%20Filename%20in%20SSIS%20using%20an%20Expression.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server SSIS package Flat File Destination file name pattern (date, time or similar)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452622/sql-server-ssis-package-flat-file-destination-file-name-pattern-date-time-or-s)

Comment: What error message are you getting?