# Use date in file name for csv-file created with Integration Services package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

I create a package in integration services to extract data on a daily basis. Is there a way to add the date or date and time to file name to make it unique?

It needs to look like this `CSV1-Delim-Elig-Date.cvs`. The `CSV1-Delim-Elig` will always be part of the file name and will be saved as a .CVS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server SSIS package Flat File Destination file name pattern (date, time or similar)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452622/sql-server-ssis-package-flat-file-destination-file-name-pattern-date-time-or-s)

Comment: This article also seems to provide a solution: [Including the Date in a Filename in SSIS using an Expression](http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Including%20the%20Date%20in%20a%20Filename%20in%20SSIS%20using%20an%20Expression.aspx)

Comment: @jpw How do I add the expression to the package in SQL 2014.

Comment: `.CVS` or `.CSV`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically generate file names you need to add an expression to the connection string property of the file connection manager.

1. Select desired connection manager.
2. In the properties pane click expressions. Then click on the ellipsis.
   [image]
3. In the property column select ConnectionString from the drop down.
   [image]
4. Click on the ellipsis in the expression column to bring up the expression editor.
   [image]
5. Enter an expression to output your desired file name. Below is an example of your desired file name with the date appended.

> "C:\\Output\\CSV1-Delim-Elig-" + REPLACE((DT_WSTR,
>   50)(DT_DBDATE)GETDATE(),"-","") + ".csv"

Comment: What about if I have a folder called "Output" in the C drive. Do I need to add that path too? and how do I add it

Comment: @JohnMolina expression sample in answer has been updated with a path.

Comment: Thanks it worked. One last question. What if I want date and time?

Comment: You can use (DT_WSTR,20)(DT_DBTIME2,5)GETDATE() to get a string with the time.